# videogular2 - playing videos loaded asynchronously does not work

Tags: angular, videogular2

Videos are being loaded from an API, but it appears that the `onPlayerReady` function is being called before the videos have finished loading and are passed. The video sources are in base64 format. The following code is being used:

```js
.getDefaultMedia()
  .subscriptions.loadedMetadata.subscribe(this.initVdo.bind(this));
```

When `initVdo` is invoked, the `isCompleted` property is false.

Is there a solution to this problem? Is it possible to initialize the `onPlayerReady` manually?

Thank you,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Videogular2` library to accomplish the above. There you don't need to play the video explicitly after it loads. The explicit `autoplay` feature of it takes care of automatically.

Use `npm install videogular2` to install the package. Use your package manager as necessary for the install.

Once after installing use the below snippet in your html:

```
<video [vgMedia]="media" #media 
  id="singleVideo" 
  preload="auto"
  type="video/mp4"
  webkit-playsinline
  playsinline
  autoplay>

  <source *ngFor="let video of sources" [src]="video.src" [type]="video.type">

</video>
```

Pass the `src` your video src.